# Is there a way to catch JBoss exception in application?

Tags: java, jboss

I have the following problem: we have set the file size limitation in JBoss:

```
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/http-listener=default/:write-attribute(name=max-post-size, value=10485760)
```

Is it possible to verify in the application if someone tries to upload file larger than the value given in this setting and show some error in the application?

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can provide multipart config in your web.xml and use it in your application to restrict the upload file size. This way you will be able to catch the exception at the application level.

Below is the sample of multipart config.

```
<multipart-config>
  <location>/tmp</location>
  <max-file-size>20848820</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>418018841</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>1048576</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Comment: So you suggest to remove this limitation from JBoss configuration?

Comment: You can keep the JBOSS settings as an extra layer for security. But it's good to define it in the application level also so that the developer will also know the file upload configurations.

Comment: OK, but when I keep this JBOSS setting, then I will be unable to display any error if user tries to upload file larger then set in this setting. So, again I will have this problem.

Comment: You can catch the below exception in your file upload code:

`org.jboss.seam.web.FileUploadException: Multipart request is larger than allowed size`

Comment: I don't get this... This exception from Jboss could not be catched in the application...